# Overriding __instancecheck__ for a C++ class with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I need to overwrite the `__instancecheck__` method for a C++ class exported using `pybind11`. AFAIK this needs to be done on the class' metaclass, but I'm not familiar with the concept.

Can I do that with `pybind11`?

Edit:

My initial attempt:

```
py::class_<Pluto> plclass(m, "Pluto");
struct PippoMeta { };
py::class_<PippoMeta> pimeta(m, "PippoMeta");
py::class_<Pippo> piclass(m, "Pippo", py::metaclass(pimeta));

plclass.def(py::init());
piclass.def(py::init());
    
pimeta.def("__instancecheck__", [](PippoMeta &, Pluto) {
   py::print("Here");
   return true;
});
```

This does not work when I load the module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from my_module import *
ImportError: Pippo: PyType_Ready failed (AttributeError: mro)!
```

If I had to write this in Python, `PippoMeta` should derive from `type`. So maybe that's the missing bit, but how to define the `py::class_` to derive from `type`?